# Some HTML nodes are not created while I execute function.Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why I am getting this error? I guess some of my HTML nodes are not created why I try to call the doSearch method. It's actually happening only second time I call this function.

I'm using React and calling this function inside componentDidUpdate lifecycle method.

Here is my HTML file where I load my script inside

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//csr.inspsearchapi.com/lib/infospace.search.js">
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/style/styles.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <script src = "bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
```

Here is my function:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const signature = this.props.signature ? this.props.signature.response.data : '';

    window.insp.search.doSearch({
      query: this.state.searchText,
      searchUrlFormat: this.state.searchText,
      signature,
      page: 1,
      containers: {
        'top': {id:'topResults'},
        'related': {id:'relatedResults'},
      },
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have container elements with IDs like that? The most likely cause I can see is `document.getElementById('topResults')` returning `null`.

Comment: Did you provide the .container to react to run?

Comment: Yes, I have it and its purpose is to receive data from this function.

Comment: @AliTorki What do you mean?